# Converting an array to a collection in Magento

Tags: magento

I have an array object that is an output of a magento fetchall from DB and i want this to be converted to an object of a Collections class so that i can implement pagination and use this collection to join with other tables. Can you please help me here ? been stuck for a long time now !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magento hasn't a built in conversor for that, but you can write you query using Collections, or load the Collection based on all ids from your array.

Comment: In Magento Enterprise 1.12, there is a method which can convert an array to a collection. See: Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract::importFromArray

Answer (score 15):

In order to convert an array to a collection object:
1> Create an instance of Varien_Db_Collection

```
$collection = new Varien_Data_Collection();
```

2> Create an instance of Varien_Object and set the array data

```
$rowObj = new Varien_Object();
$rowObj->setData($row);
```

3> Finally add the Varien_Object to Collection instance

```
$collection->addItem($rowObj);
```

4> Now $collection is a collection object.

Comment: in [tag:magento]-1.8 there is no class `Varien_Db_Collection`. I'm getting this error `Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Db_Collection' not found`

Comment: Try to use 'Varien_Data_Collection_Db' instead of 'Varien_Db_Collection'.

Comment: I was getting odd errors with `Varien_Data_Collection_Db` but `Varien_Data_Collection` works fine with the posted code in this answer

Comment: I've just used the code above, and It works fine. So, This is one should be the correct answer and not one provided by @Rafael Kassner. Obsviouly, Using Varien_Data_Collection class..

Answer (score 3):

Also, populating a collection can be done with the `addItem` method.

Comment: can you elaborate this ? So i have an array, can i instantiate a collection and add each item in the array to the collection by using the additem method of the collection object ?

Comment: Yes, you'll (probably) have to loop through your array and then call `$collection->addItem($item)` on each item to add to the collection.

Comment: @Nick: which class object is this `$collection`?

Answer (score -1):

If you have an array of ids `$product_ids`, you can use:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addIdFilter($product_ids);
```