# Magento, additem to custom collection

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to add some items to a custom created collection. Reading [Alan Storm varien data collection](http://alanstorm.com/magento_collections) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911536/converting-an-array-to-a-collection-in-magento) I got to a couple of different options.

Here is one option using Varien_Data_Collection:

```
    $myResultCollection = new Varien_Data_Collection();
    $mybanner = new Varien_Object();
    foreach($myBannersCollection as $banner){
        $mybanner = $banner;
        $search_text = explode(",", $banner->getsearch_text());
        foreach ($search_text as $txt){
            if (stripos($currentProdName,$txt) !== false) {
                $myResultCollection->addItem($mybanner);
            }
        }
    }
```

This code throws the following error:

```
Item (Dts_Banners_Model_Bannersadmin) with the same id "10" already exist
```

And here is another variation of the code, using my custom collection from a model I currently use:

```
    $myResultCollection = Mage::getModel('banners/bannersadmin');
    foreach($myBannersCollection as $banner){
        $search_text = explode(",", $banner->getsearch_text());
        foreach ($search_text as $txt){
            if (stripos($currentProdName,$txt) !== false) {
                $myResultCollection->addItem($banner);
            }
        }
    }
```

But this one shows the following error (not showing everything, is way to long):

```
Invalid method Dts_Banners_Model_Bannersadmin::addItem(Array
(
    [0] => Dts_Banners_Model_Bannersadmin Object
        (
            [_eventPrefix:protected] => core_abstract
            [_eventObject:protected] => object
            [_resourceName:protected] => banners/bannersadmin
            [_resource:protected] => 
            [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => banners/bannersadmin_collection
            [_cacheTag:protected] => 
            [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
            [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
            .......
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem #1:** Items being added to a `Varien_Data_Collection` instance need to have distinct IDs in the context of the collection.

**Problem #2:** `Dts_Banners_Model_Bannersadmin` is not an instance of `Varien_Data_Collection`.

Comment: For the 2nd one. In Magento not all the collection "inherit" from the basic Varien_Data_Collection?

Comment: All typical Magento collections use `Varien_Data_Collection`; those which use Magento's ORM for DB do so by via `Varien_Data_Collection_Db`.

Comment: Was not aware, now checking the Alan Storm site I realized so. Will try out using it and see what happens. What do you recommend, use `Varien_Data_Collection` or `Varien_Data_Collection_Db`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. Inside the `for..each` I was trying to add the same object several times and offcourse the error was correct as the ID was being repeated. Correct code as follows:

```
$myResultCollection = new Varien_Data_Collection();
$mybanner = new Varien_Object();
$found = false;
foreach($myBannersCollection as $banner){
    $mybanner = $banner;
    $search_text = explode(",", $banner->getsearch_text());
    foreach ($search_text as $txt){
        if (stripos($currentProdName,$txt) !== false) {
            $mybanner = $banner;
            $myResultCollection->addItem($mybanner);
            $found = true;
        }
        if ($found) break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**  @benmarks your answer to my first snippet is correct, as commented here on my asnwer. But on the second one I'm not so sure. In Magento not all the collection "inherit" from the basic Varien_Data_Collection?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not all the collection 'inherit' from the basic Varien_Data_Collection" (the grammar is throwing me off a bit). All typical collections inherit from `Varien_Data_Collection`, which would indicate that `Dts_Banners_Model_Bannersadmin` is *not* a collection class, something I'd expect from its instantiation via `getModel()`. Typically collection classes are accessed as resource models. A convenience method `getCollection()` exists for Magento data models (instances of `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` initialized with `_init()`).

Comment: Sorry for my english, not native speaker here. I was trying to say that I thought that all collections inherited from `Varien_Data_Collection` and therefore I could instantiate my model to it. But I see that is not possible. About the `getCollection()`, yes, I know it exists and I use it. Maybe I'm just doing it everything wrong, I'm new to Magento/Zend framework. What I'm trying to do is to create a new collection that will have only the elements that accomplish some given condition and later this new collection will be used to display those elements on the product details page.