# Pager error in custom collection magento

Tags: php, arrays, magento, exception, pager

I have an array populated with some objects that are not from magento. I have fetched them from 3rd party software and I am showing them in magento grid. The grid population is complete. But when I try to add a pager to its collection, it throws an exception. here is the exception text

[image: Magento Error]

I have seen on some articles that there is a difference between magento collection and an ordinary array in php. I am new to magento so I require help in it. I have also tried to convert it to magento collection as proposed in

[Convert an array to a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911536/converting-an-array-to-a-collection-in-magento)

but its not working either.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Please try below code.

```
protected $collection;
public $collection1;
public $rowObj;
protected function _construct()
{
$currentPage = (empty($_REQUEST['p'])) ? 1 : $_REQUEST['p'];
$setLimit = (empty($_REQUEST['limit'])) ? 9 : $_REQUEST['limit'];
$collection1 = new Varien_Data_Collection(); 
$rowObj = new Varien_Object();
 $this->collection = array_merge($this->getPreviousLead(), $this->getLeadsData()); 
$this->collection = array_merge($this->collection, $this->getContactsData());
 $this->collection = array_merge($this->collection, $this->getUpdateLeads()); 
$this->collection->setPage($currentPage, $setLimit);
$rowObj->setData($this->collection); 

$collection1->addItem($rowObj); 

}
```

Hope this will work for you!

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am not fully using resource model to fetch values from DB. I am using like

$this->getCollectionFromMagento();
and
$this->getCollectionFromSugarCrm();
$collection=array_merge($this->getCollectionFromMagento(),$this->getCollectionFromSugarCrm());

how can I use this collection to add pager in it ?

Comment: Here It is

protected $collection;
public $collection1;
public $rowObj;
    protected function _construct() {
        $collection1 = new Varien_Data_Collection();
        $rowObj = new Varien_Object();
        $this->collection = array_merge($this->getPreviousLead(), $this->getLeadsData());
        $this->collection = array_merge($this->collection, $this->getContactsData());
        $this->collection = array_merge($this->collection, $this->getUpdateLeads());
        $rowObj->setData($this->collection);
        $collection1->addItem($rowObj);
    }

Comment: I am still facing an exception that I have added in the above answer . Can you please see.